# Have character vector evaluate as language type in R

Tags: r

How can I have a character vector behave as a language type in R?

I have two attempts to assign some characters:

```
> formula2
[1] "d_var ~ var1 + var2 + var3 ... "


> formula
d_dvar ~ var 1 + var2 + var3...
```

How can I coerce the first into behaving like the second?

For additional info, `typeof(formula2)` returns `character` and `typeof(formula)` returns `language`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. `formula <- model$lm$terms[[2]] ~ model$lm$terms[[3]]` works fine here (even without defining model).

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: you can use `formula(model)` or `paste0(model$lm$terms[[2]]," ~ ", model$lm$terms[[3]] )`

Comment: @MamounBenghezal Thanks this resolved the issue, please feel free to write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MamounBenghezal stated in his comment I used the `formula()` function to make the character type behave like a language type.

There is also an `as.formula()` .